# Pass specific service account key to Google Storage API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to authenticate with Google Storage by passing a service account key manually as a Json object.  I am trying to pass a specific service account to be used and not the default service account created by the project.  However even when I pass the key of my specific service account, the error I get is still using the default service account.  How do I tell the google storage api to use the key being passed to it instead?

```
var accessKey = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "...",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "...",
  "client_email": "myserviceaccount@gcp-serviceaccounts-keys.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "..."
};
const projectId = " ...";
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({projectId, accessKey});
const bucket = storage.bucket('test-bucket-aa');
```

The error I get:

```
Error: gcp-myprojectid@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strongly preferable to keep the key out of the source.

The Storage client wants a reference to the key's filename.

See: [Storage examples](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html#Storage-examples)

Put the string in your source into a file e.g. `key.json` and then:

```
const keyFilename = "/path/to/key.json";
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId,
  keyFilename: keyFilename
});
```

##### Using ADCs with Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage

```sh
PROJECT=... # Your Project ID
ACCOUNT=... # Your Service Account
FUNCTION=... # Your Cloud Function

# Create Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--description="Used by Cloud Functions to Access Cloud Storage" \
--display-name="Cloud Functions Storage Accessor" \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

ROLE="roles/storage.objectAdmin"

# Permit the Service Account `storageAdmin`
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/${ROLE}

# Deploy the Cloud Functions to run as the Service Account
# Cloud Functions uses ADCs to auth as the Service Account
gcloud functions deploy ${FUNCTION} \
... \
--service-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

> **NOTE** Using the above approach, your code is simpler using just `const storage = new Storage();`, the platform auth's using the Service Accounts credentials.

> **NOTE** It's preferable to set the IAM policy on a specific bucket rather than the project (all its buckets), see: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#project-level_roles_vs_bucket-level_roles

Perhaps, instead of `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding`, you could:

```sh
BUCKET=gs://[[YOUR-BUCKET]]

gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:${EMAIL}:roles/${ROLE} ${BUCKET}
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam#ch

Comment: I am using cloud function and don't have access to storage, how do I hard code key?

Comment: You should *not* hardcode the key. A solution is to deploy the Cloud Function to run under its own user-defined Service Account. Then, in the Cloud Function, you (really) should use Application Default Credentials (ADCs). ADCs will detect the Function's Service Account and use that. You then don't need to create a key (a good thing) for the Service Account unless you test it off-GCP. You just need to assign the Service Account  a role that includes `storage.objects.get`

Comment: Added an explanation to my answer